# foreach loop does not print all values in view page from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

> how to print all values using foreach loop.i used the loop but  it
>   print only last values from the array values.

```
query=$this->Common_model->getTableData('table name', array('field name' => $param))->result();


     foreach($query as $rows)
     {

     $user=$rows->userby;
     $data['user_status']=$rows->status;

      $data['user']=$user;

      $status=$this->Common_model->getTableData('table name', array('id' =>$data['user_status']))->row();

      $data['status']=$status->name;


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should had been:

```
$query=$this->Common_model->getTableData('table name', array('field name' => $param));  //remove ->results()


     foreach($query->result() as $rows)  // correction here.
     {

     $user=$rows->userby;
     $data['user_status']=$rows->status;

      $data['user']=$user;

      $status=$this->Common_model->getTableData('table name', array('id' =>$data['user_status']))->row();

      $data['status']=$status->name;


     }
```

The `result()` function is called everytime, to traverse through rows one-by-one (sequentially).

Comment: foreach($query->result() as $rows)  // correction here. i changed its prints last value only

Comment: did you remove the `->results()` in the first line of the code?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting only last values is that you are assigning the values to same index which overrides the previous value. you should try this

```
foreach($query->result() as $rows)  // correction here.
     {

     $user=$rows->userby;
     $data['user_status'][]=$rows->status;

      $data['user'][]=$user;

      $status=$this->Common_model->getTableData('table name', array('id' =>$data['user_status']))->row();

      $data['status'][]=$status->name;


     }
```